# "alternative optimization" method for multiple metric learning

Tags: mathematical-optimization, metric

During the training process of metric learning, if the cost function is  convex, then I can use the gradient descent method, and get the optimal solution.

Now,  I want to train N(N may be very big, such as 100) metrics from a training set, and one method is adjust the cost function to enable these N metric to  combine as a big metric matrix and use the gradient descent method, However, if the N is very big, this method is not very good,  in this condition, is there some "alternative optimization"  method I can use?, 
        Is it ok that I fix 2th~Nth metrics and make  gradient descent for only 1th metric and then fix 1th, 3th~Nth metrics and make gradient descent for only the 2th metric. 
Is there some essential condition  for such "alternative optimization"  method

Comment: What gradient descent method are you using?

Comment: This depends heavily on the function you are optimising (how separable are the dimensions). Sometimes you have to do it all at once, sometimes one at a time is fine, sometimes one at a time or batches, with multiple passes (batches with multiple passes is the compromise I often favour)

Answer (score 0):

the AO method can't get the optimal solution , even the local optimal solution can't be. because the N convex problems can't reach the KKT conditions at the same time.